# Best approach using Qt for a messaging application like Skype

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebkit

Which widgets should I use to implement a chat with the similar style of Skype for desktop? I need to put both incoming and outcoming messages, images, and other stuff. I think QWebView is a good choice but I don't know how to append HTML code. Which widget would you recommend me for this purpose?

Regards,

Comment: I suggest you read through [this article](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/richtext-common-tasks.html).